# Mysql lock concurrent read/update of row

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, innodb

I have table, and many (too many) requests for selecting from it a single row. After selecting a row, the script run update query to set a flag that is that row had been "selected". But as we have too many requests per time, in period between one thread select a row, and update its flag, **another thread have time to select the same row**.

Select query get one row from the table, ordering it by some field and using LIMIT 0, 1. I need that DB just skip the row, that had been selected before.

The engine is InnoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Just before you start a transaction, call the following:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
```

This will ensure that if you read a row with a flag, it'll still be that way when you update it within the same transaction.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id_site
INTO @site
FROM table1 WHERE flag = 0 ORDER BY field LIMIT 0,1;

UPDATE table1 SET flag = 1 WHERE id_site = @site;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I have 

    SELECT id_site, name FROM table1 WHERE flag = 0 ORDER BY field LIMIT 0,1

and then

    UPDATE table1 SET flag = 1 WHERE id_site = :id_site

You see, the second query use id_site value from previous ones. How can I do this in one transaction?

Comment: I have a code like this http://pastebin.com/iWCUBs8P But I`ve got an error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Comment: I would suggest putting a block of code like this into a stored procedure